# Nuxt.js Prismic.io Integration Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, content-management-system, nuxt.js, prismic.io

Following this [simple tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/create-a-blazing-fast-modern-blog-with-nuxt-and-prismic-7d19935d849c) as an intro to [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org) with a [hosted headless CMS](https://prismic.io).

I got to the end, put my API key into the required file, but I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

at line 21, ie:

```
const header = PrismicDom.RichText.asText(blog_post.data.blog_post_title);
```

It's a basic scaffolded Nuxt.js project from scratch, so pretty clean, not much going on here.

No one in the comments seems to have encountered this issue. Any ideas?

(left most of default nuxt.js CSS and combined with the tutorial's, that really shouldn't be the issue though.)

```
<template>
  <section class="blog-post">
    <h1 class="title">{{ header }}</h1>
    <p class="paragraph">{{ content }}</p>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  import Prismic from "prismic-javascript";
  import PrismicDom from "prismic-dom" //importing the Dom
  import PrismicConfig from "./../prismic.config.js";
  export default {
    async asyncData() {
      const api = await Prismic.getApi(PrismicConfig.apiEndpoint);
      let blog_post = {};
      const results = await api.query(
        Prismic.Predicates.at("document.type", "blog_post"),
        { lang: "en-gb" } //This is a Prismic query option
      );
      blog_post = results.results[0];
      const header = PrismicDom.RichText.asText(blog_post.data.blog_post_title);
      const content = PrismicDom.RichText.asText(blog_post.data.blog_post_content);
      return {
        blog_post,
        header,
        content
      };
    }
  };
</script>

<style>
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .blog-post {
    margin: 25px 0;
    padding: 0 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .title {
    font-family:
    'Quicksand',
    'Source Sans Pro',
    -apple-system,
    BlinkMacSystemFont,
    'Segoe UI',
    Roboto,
    'Helvetica Neue',
    Arial,
    sans-serif;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #35495e;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.subtitle {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #526488;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.links {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
p {
  color: #000;
  margin: 15px 0 5px;
  max-width: 450px;
  line-height: 1.44;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hey, I'm suspecting multiple things, perhaps you should check the value of `results` before to make sure everything looks alright? Same for the Network request. Have you created a blog post document in Prismic? If no that would explain why the results array is emply :)

Also the tutorial you're looking at seems quite old now (2019), Nuxt.js, and Prismic, have evolved quite a lot since! This article might be helpful:https://prismic.io/docs/technologies/using-prismic-with-nuxtjs-vuejs

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that, 

There is a blog post document in prismic so empty array shouldn't be the cause.

I had started peeking the docs after I posted and I'll refactor to follow that instead of the potential outdated tutorial article, thanks for the reply!